# How to get transfer confirmation from bank(by PHP)?

Tags: php, transactions, banking, bank

currently in progress making my first website, about selling something.
But, i want the payments via offline. The first is direct payment and second is via bank transfer (to certain account, my account).

how the get the transaction confirmation from bank to my machine(server) and then my machine automatically send confirmation to customer?
or the bank send automatically send the confirmation right after transaction?(make some agreement to the bank)

Comment: You need to have a look at the Bank's API what the return parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

the best and secure way is to use `paypal` i am not sure about that particular bank, whether that bank is offering any `API` or not, `paypal` is the best for online tansactions

Answer (score -2):

currently in progress making my first website, about selling something. But, i want the payments via offline. The first is direct payment and second is via bank transfer (to certain account, my account).

You Can try the code below sir!..replace my email and test it!..

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; // Test Paypal API URL
$paypal_id='itprowenkz@gmail.com'; // Business email ID
?>